# How can I compute if a value is prime or not faster?

Tags: c, algorithm

My programs runs well in my compiler but it shows time limit exceeds in online contest compiler.
First line of input will contain a number N = number of test cases. Next N lines will contain number n as test case where 0<=n<=1000000000
Here is my code.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void main()
   {   
   long t,n,i;
   int f = 0;
   scanf("%lu",&t);
   while(t--)
   {
       scanf("%lu",&n);
       f=0;
       if(n==0 || n==1)
       {
           printf("NOT PRIME\n");
       }
       else 
       {
       for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
       {
           if(n%i == 0)
           {
               printf("NOT PRIME\n");
               f =1;
               break;
            }
       }
       if(f==0)
       {
           printf("PRIME\n"); 
       }
   }
   }
}
```

How can I execute this program faster. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an even more fast way than the chosen answer you might be interested in probabilistic methods: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=primalityTesting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate to square root of `n` instead of `n/2`. Also you can pre-calculate all the prime factors in the range of square root of 1000000000 before the while loop. Then try to divide n with the prime factors that are less than or equal to `sqrt(n)` to check if it is prime or not.

The `for` loop:

```
(i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2) // skip 2 because it's the only even prime
```

Comment: Sorry I cant get you. Can u please edit this for loop and explain me clearly.
Thanks.

Comment: Per my answer below, you can for(i=3;i<=sqrt(n);i+=2) if you first rule check that the number is not even.

Comment: +1 Pre-processed sqrt(n) & having a list of prime numbers under `sqrt(LONG_MAX)` + check odd numbers only

Answer (score 4):

Also you only need to test odd numbers for primality (two being the only even prime).
And compile with optimization, e.g. -O3 if using gcc.

Answer (score 2):

You can make with increment 2:

My function to verify if a number is prime:

```
bool check(int n)
{
    int i, j;
    bool isprime;
    if(n%2 == 0 || n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
         isprime = false;
    }
    else if(n == 2 || n == 3)
    {
        isprime = true;
    }
    else 
    {
    for(i = 3; i<n; i+=2)
    {
        if(n%i == 0)
        {
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
        else if(i == n-2)
        {
            isprime = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    return isprime;
}
```

Remembering that call a function is less fast than use directly in main function.

Comment: Using the condition to finish loop 'for' that Tahlil said above, the perform will be faster.

Answer (score -1):

Without changing your algorithm:

```
for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
```

might be faster as:

```
for(i=2, m=n/2; i<=m; ++i)
```

you only calculate the end value once, and preincrement doesn' compute an intermediate value like the post increment does.

However, with decent compiler optimizations, both of these will already be done.
Without looking at the generate assembly, it is hard to do any aggressive optimization.